How to execute gum functions when attached to a program using Frida core
I am using frida-core to attach to a program and execute js code.
I would like to use gum functions and get results in the attached program's pid.
Any way to accomplish this once I'm attached to the program via device.attach?
In the next code you can see I execute  frida_gum_sys::gum_process_enumerate_ranges and I do get results, but the result is from the current process instead of the attached one, even though I'm attached to the program let session = local_device.attach(crackme_pid).unwrap();
use std::ptr;

use frida::Frida;
use frida_gum_sys::{gboolean, gpointer, GumRangeDetails};
use lazy_static::lazy_static;

lazy_static! {
    static ref FRIDA: Frida = unsafe { Frida::obtain() };
}

unsafe extern "C" fn process_range(
    range: *const GumRangeDetails,
    _user_data: gpointer,
) -> gboolean {
    let r = &*range;

    println!(
        "range = {:?}, protection = {:?}, file = {:?}",
        r.range, r.protection, r.file
    );
    true as gboolean // Return true to continue enumeration
}

fn main() {
    let device_manager = frida::DeviceManager::obtain(&FRIDA);
    let local_device = device_manager.get_local_device().unwrap();
    let processes = local_device.enumerate_processes();

    let crackme_pid: Vec<&frida::Process> = processes
        .iter()
        .filter(|p| p.get_name() == "crackme-01")
        .collect();
    let crackme_pid = crackme_pid.first().unwrap().get_pid();
    let session = local_device.attach(crackme_pid).unwrap();

    let script_source = r#"
        console.log("test");
    "#;

    let mut script_option = frida::ScriptOption::default();
    let script = session
        .create_script(script_source, &mut script_option)
        .unwrap();

    script.load().unwrap();

    unsafe {
        frida_gum_sys::gum_process_enumerate_ranges(1 | 2, Some(process_range), ptr::null_mut());
    }

    script.unload().unwrap();
}

I am currently using Frida rust bindings but I just need to know how to do this in any bindings.
